# CakePHP 3 prefix rounting with plugin one more time

Tags: cakephp, routes, cakephp-3.x

In main `routes.php` i prepare some rounting for plugins with prefix like this: `/prefix/pluginName/controller/action`:

```
Router::prefix('admin', function (RouteBuilder $routes) {
    $routes->plugin('ContactManager', function ($routes) {
        $routes->connect('/', [
            'controller' => 'Contacts',
            'action' => 'index'
        ]);

        $routes->connect('/:controller/:action');
    });
});
```

And works perfectly, but I would like move code about routing plugin to `routes.php` in plugin directory, like this:

**routes.php** (main)

```
Router::prefix('admin', function (RouteBuilder $routes) {
    Plugin::routes(); // Run plugins routes
});
```

**routes.php** (plugin):

```
Router::plugin('ContactManager', function ($routes) {
    $routes->connect('/', [
        'controller' => 'Contacts',
        'action' => 'index'
    ]);

    $routes->connect('/:controller/:action');
});
```

but the URL doesn't work.

Plugins should be independet from used prefix.

Maybe I forgot something?

Tested on WAMP and CakePHP 3.5.5

Comment: did you load the plugin routes? `CakePlugin::load('ContactManager', ['route' => true]);`

Comment: @shahonseven: yes

Comment: Anybody know How to `routes.php` in Plugin directory should be works with prefix?

Comment: I have a very similar problem trying to nest prefix inside plugins. I hope someone can answer this question.